# How to list information about all Alfresco's files (Postgres SQL)?

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

A file node representation in Alfresco persistent layer:

- **content** is stored in `ALFRESCO_HOME\alf_data\contentstore\` folder
- **metadata** are stored in `relational database` (default: PostgreSQL)
- **information for text searching** (Lucene) are stored in Solr's document database

Which Postgres tables are used to keep metadata of new uploaded file? 
How to list information about all Alfresco's files (Postgres SQL)?

Comment: The database schema is meant to be internal--you shouldn't hit it directly.

Comment: I know, but I need to export the list of ten millions Alfresco's files (name, path, size) to make sure that all files have been imported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The tables that keep files metadata:

[image]

## Listing information about all Alfresco's files - Postgres SQL:

```
SELECT 
  n.id, 
  npn.string_value as filename,
  cu.content_size,
  cu.content_url,   
  n.uuid, 
  n.audit_created
FROM alf_node as n
  join alf_node_properties npn on 
     (npn.node_id=n.id and npn.actual_type_n=6 and npn.qname_id in 
       (select id from alf_qname where local_name='name'))
  join alf_node_properties npc on 
     (npc.node_id=n.id and npc.actual_type_n=21 and npc.qname_id in 
       (select id from alf_qname where local_name='content'))
  join alf_content_data cd on (cd.id = npc.long_value)
  join alf_content_url cu on (cd.content_url_id = cu.id)
where 
  n.type_qname_id in (
    select id from alf_qname where local_name='content'
  )
```